# Пересекаются ли значения слов "оговорить" и "обговорить"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

[Вот](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) статья о слове *оговорить* на Грамоте. Мне кажется, что 2-е значение там близко к значению слова "обговорить" (обсудить). Как вы считаете, если добавить в примерах для 2-го значения "оговорить" букву Б, изменится ли принципиально смысл и если да, то как можно конкретизировать этот нюанс?

Вообще, я вроде понимаю разницу между "условиться" и "обсудить", но нет ли каких-то ещё случаев, когда разницу понять затруднительно и, соответственно, выбрать подходящее слово?

Если брать те четыре примера, то в первом и последнем "обговорено" не подходит, однако замена во втором и третьем примере не меняет смысла определённым образом, на мой взгляд. Приведу эти фразы:

> *Условились встретиться, оговорив предварительно время и место.
>
> Надо хорошенько оговорить каждый пункт контракта.*

Answer (score 1):

Что касается значений слова "**обговорить**", мне близка трактовка [этого](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) источника.

Это прежде всего аналог слова "*обсудить (неформально)*". Второе приводимое значение — просторечная замена слова "оговорить" в его обычном значении. Просторечность такого употребления мне видится в смешивании *значений* слов "**оговорить**" (прийти к конкретному решению = условиться; конкретизировать что-либо словесно, напр. в документе) и "**обговорить**" (обсудить - с неизвестным результатом).

Если перейти к примеру из "Грамоты" с "*хорошенько*", мне он кажется не вполне убедительным: явная *неформальность* стиля предполагает бо́льшую естественность употребления слова "**обговорить**" (обговорить хорошенько - если имеется в виду предварительное обсуждение). Употребленное же слово (в сочетании с "хорошенько") оставляет смысловую неясность, что именно предлагается: заняться *обсуждением* пунктов контракта (хорошенько обговорить их перед составлением текста) или *в самом тексте* тщательно оговорить ограничения, цифры и т. п. То есть в зависимости от желаемого смысла уместно было бы либо "**хорошенько обговорить**" пункты контракта, либо "**тщательно оговорить**" что-либо в самих пунктах.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Вы всё очень верно подметили, в том числе и о смешении, всё уяснил до конца. По ссылке только не понял, как это второе значение "обговорить" соответствует первому значению "оговорить" (оклеветать).

Comment: И еще: если уж вы обособляете "в зависимости от", тогда и в начале запятую, наверно, надо поставить? Правильно?

Comment: Артем, я думаю, что в значении "оклеветать" люди _не_ подменяют слово "оговорить" словом "обговорить" (находят другие глаголы, напр. "оболгать"). Поэтому словарной статье (п. 2) по моей ссылке не помешала бы соотв. оговорка.

Comment: А насчёт запятых что-нибудь скажете?